# Docker container crashes sporadically with "Exited (1)" status

Tags: docker, debian, docker-compose

We have a weird issue that some of the containers crash from time to time. We have total of three containers, lets name them A, B and C. C container starts perfectly fine all the time, but the A and B containers crash randomly (usually A container, but sometimes B). Weird thing is that only one of the container crashes, not both. It can be either A or B that crash.

This happens only with the device restart. We are booting the device every day (docker containers are started on boot), and after the boot the container just sometimes exits with `Exited (1)`. When container is excited I can not run `docker logs container_id`, the command just freezes. When device is rebooted once more, the containers usually start working fine and I am able to run `docker logs container_id` but "crash logs" and "non-crash logs" look completely same and do not give any insightful information.

Any suggestion on how to debug this or pinpoint the issue?

Docker version is: Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6
Host is: Debian Stretch

EDIT: docker inspect content added

Inspect content for container A:
https://gist.github.com/maksimluzik/297a0f986e6cc4870fb847aaa1111bee

Inspect content for container B:
https://gist.github.com/maksimluzik/1eae458246577b50969fc9a4fecc6d65

Comment: Try checking if there are any hostname conflicts or the port conflicts. Also can you post the output of the following command:
docker inspect $Your_Process_Id

Comment: Added both container inspect outputs. We don't have any port bindings on those containers. It definitely could be related to the conflicts of some sort, but have not found it out myself.

Comment: Try increasing the memory limit. I think we had the same error when docker had no more memory.

Comment: @MaksimLuzik you have added the ouput for the running containers. The output of the exited container (the one that is stopped automatically) gives us the better insight of why it is failed. Can you post that if possible.

Comment: @Vamsi I will add one as the container crashes again.

Comment: It is the same issue as with the `docker logs container_id`. I am unable to run `docker inspect container_id` when the container is crashed. The command just freezes.